# Cannot use pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pyinstaller, waf

I am running windows and trying to use the pyinstaller module. When I run `pyinstaller filename.py` in cmd, the following error occurs:

```sh
Fatal error: PyInstaller does not include a pre-compiled bootloader for your
platform. For more details and instructions how to build the bootloader see
<https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/bootloader-building.html>
```

So I tried building the bootloader using the link that was provided. There is a step that says to run the command `python ./waf all`. When I ran that, I got the following error:

```sh
python: can't open file './waf': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I tried installing the waftools module to see if it would remedy this. It requires that I run the following two commands:

```
pip install -I waftools
wafinstall
```

When I run the first command, it works fine, but when I run the second command, I get a long traceback (found [here](https://pastebin.com/FpRN1RsH)), ending with this error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.\\waf-waf-1.8.19\\waf'
```

This is where I get stuck, and I do not even know for sure if this would fix my original issue if I get it working correctly. What should I do?

Comment: It's mostly due to a broken or outdated pyinstaller installation. There should be a matching bootloader when installed correctly. How did you install pyinstaller?

Comment: @Dschoni i tried `pip install pyloader`, and then downloading from source, doing `python setup.py install`

Comment: `pip install pyinstaller` should get you a working pyinstaller with bootloader.

Comment: i figured it out, pyinstaller doesnt support version 3.8.3 of python so I downgraded to python 3.7

Comment: @Matthew then answer the question yourself and accept the answer, in order to show that this problem was solved.